# How to update value in row using multiple queries python flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update the value in the column 'score' at the row where student entry column = rowId.id. It is giving the error, **List object has no attribute 'id'**. below is my table structure, and the code I am trying to execute.

```
class studentTimetable(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'studentTimetable'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    SACE_no = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey('student.SACE_no'), unique=False, nullable=False)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey('courses.name'), nullable=False)
    checkpoint = db.relationship('feedback', backref='studentTimetable',lazy=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.SACE_no

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'subject': self.subject,
            'SACE_no': self.SACE_no,
        }


class feedback(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feedback'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    studentEntry = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('studentTimetable.id'), nullable=False)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.id

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'studentEntry': self.studentEntry,
            'score': self.score,
        }
```

code:

```
@login_required
@app.route('/dashboard/<subject>/<sace>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def studentEdit(subject, sace):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        assessment = float(request.form.get('assessments'))
        attendance = float(request.form.get('attendance'))
        focus = float(request.form.get('focus'))
        print(focus)
        totalCheckpoint = float(assessment+attendance+focus)
        rowId = studentTimetable.query.filter_by(subject=subject, SACE_no=sace).all()
        checkpointUpdate = feedback.query.filter_by(studentEntry=rowId.id).first()
        checkpointUpdate.score = totalCheckpoint
        db.session.commit()
        '''for i in rowId:
            rowId = i.to_dict()
        print(rowId['id'])'''
        

        return render_template('students.html', subject=subject)
    return render_template('edit.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
both `__repr__` functions in the tables were removed, rowId was changed to a `.first()` as only one record should be present, and `db.session.merge(checkpointUpdate)` was added above the `db.session.commit()`